# To prove that if $ab\equiv ac\bmod n$ and $(a,n)=1$ then $b\equiv c\bmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, gcd-and-lcm

To prove that if $ab \equiv ac\bmod n$ and $(a,n)=1$ then $b\equiv c \bmod n$

I write as

$1=ar+ns$

$ac=ab+nq$

I have to prove $c=b+nr$

How do I manipulate equations to reach conclusion

Thanks

Comment: If $a(b-c)=mn$, for some $m$, and $(a,n)=1$, then what can you say about $a$ and $m$? If $a$ is a factor of $mn$, and $(a,n)=1$, then can you say $a$ divides $m$? Now the answer should be clear.

Comment: Note that you've used $r$ twice here. In general, those will be different, and should therefore be denied by different letters.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes i got it. Thanks

Comment: @Gathdi Welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your notation is a little wrong. I think what you're asking is:

> If $$ab \equiv ac \mod{n}$$
>   and $(a,n)=1$, then $b \equiv c \mod{n}$

As you suggest, write $a(b-c)=nq$ and $1=ar+ns$.

Multiplying through by $r$, we have $ar(b-c)=nqr$, so $(1-ns)(b-c)=nqr$.

It follows that $b-c=n(qr+s(b-c))$, so $b-c$ is divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ac=ab+nq$$
means $a(c-b)=nq$, in other words $n$ divides $a(c-b)$. But
$$1=ar+ns$$
so either $n=\pm1$ or $n$ does not divide $a$.

If $n=\pm1$ then as $b=c+(b-c)(1)=c+(c-b)(-1)$, we have $b\equiv c\pmod n$.

If $n$ does not divide $a$, but $n$ divides $a(c-b)$, then $n$ must divide $c-b$, i.e. again $b\equiv c\pmod n$.

Answer (score 1):

As $\gcd(a,n)=1$, we have a *Bézout's relation*: $\; ua+vn=1$, so $ua\equiv 1\mod n$.

Now $\quad ab\equiv ac\implies uab\equiv uac\iff 1\cdot b\equiv 1\cdot c\mod n$.

Comment: I know nothing of rings yet

Comment: @Gathdi: OK. I just meant that in this case, it's almost obvious. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

n divides ab-ac or a(b-c).

n cannot divide a.

That implies n divides (b-c)

Edit: since $ n | a *(b-c)$ , prime factorisation of $  a * (b-c)  $ should contain or include prime factorisation of $ n$.

Since $a, n$ are co-prime, $a$ does not contain any prime factors of $n$, thus $ b-c $ should contain all the prime factorisation of $n$, meaning $ n | b-c $

Comment: BTW you can write math like this $n\mid ab-ac$ (which is entered as `$n\mid ab-ac$`). For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: BTW the way [your answer is currently written](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1928080/1) it is not clear where you use that fact that $n$ and $a$ are coprime (i.e. $\gcd(n,a)=1$). It is not true that $n\mid a(b-c)$ and $n\nmid a$ implies $n\mid b-c$.

Comment: Any example how it is not true would be really helpful.

Comment: Take $n=4$, $a=2$, $b=2$, $c=0$. Clearly $4\mid 2\cdot 2$ and $4\nmid2$.